# Jquery select only part of a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Sorry if it is a basic question but I am stuck. I am trying to change the price in the following code:

```
<body>
 <div id="price">
   <span class="title"> price</span>
 $30
 </div>   
</body>
```

I tried that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#price').text('$31');
</script>
```

but of course it remove the span. I tried a few combinations with .not but nothing seems to work. Unfortunately, I cannot add a class to the price, which would make my life easier. Anybody knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contents()` returns all children including text nodes. Then you just get only the text nodes with a `filter()`, and voila.

```
$('#price').contents().filter(function (index) {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && index == 2; // both conditions to make sure it's the correct node
}).replaceWith(' $31');
```

Comment: @Nathan: Don't you need to take empty text nodes into account?

Comment: @Andrew yes, my bad. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Btw Cyril, you'll want to test what the correct `index` is for your particular code. It's 2 here because 0 is the start of the div (before the span... an empty text node) and 1 is the span.

Comment: @Pinkie, it seems `text()` doesn't work on text nodes because jQuery is trying to call `createTextNode()` on a text node!!! I've changed it to `replaceWith()`.

Comment: Damn, that was quick. Thanks a lot, guys. I don't feel too bad asking this question, it wasn't as trivial as I thought

Comment: Glad we could help. Thanks to @Andrew and @Pinkie for pointing out that my first two attempts didn't quite work.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a RegExp replace like:

```
var $price = $('#price'),
    priceHTML = $price.html(),
    newPrice = '$31';

$price.html(priceHTML.replace(/\$\d+/, newPrice));
```

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/2HTjq/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a label or span around the $30 and then change that.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your HTML like so:

```
<div id="priceContainer">
  <span class="title">price</span>
  <span id="price">$30</span>
</div>
```

And the jQuery just as it is, really:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#price").text("$31");
</script>
```